# Maven dependencies doesnot add and maven central index keeps updating and doesnot completes its update even when it has been updating for 12 hours

Tags: eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee

I have tried to add maven dependencies in my maven project (eclipse luna) but it gives artifact id required error.
I found the solution on the internet that updating the central index would solve the problem but I have tried to update the index but it keeps updating the index and updating doesnot end.
I have let it to be updated for almost 8-12 hours but its still updating and 
I am not still able to add maven dependencies

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to fill in the groupId, artifactId and version (GAV values) for maven to fetch the required dependency from mavencentral. Since you didn't, no amount of waiting is going to do anything.

Comment: I have filled the required fields still no result. and if I click okay there are many errors.

Comment: My update finally Finished and everything is working properly